# In listview, how to update all children widgets, when one is tapped?

Tags: listview, flutter, gesture

What I have is comments for an article, and each comment is a seperate widget. Once a comment widget is tapped, its color changes, and editing options show up for that comment. But, how can I allow only one comment to be edited at once?

So, each comment widget has a bool propery "isEditing", and once a comment is tapped, all others comments "isEditing" should change to false, and tapped comment to true.

I sadly cannot show code (company is very strict about this), and I dont expect a code in replies. Just a general idea on how to handle this.

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: You could open a dialog for editing the comment which would restrict the user to only being able to edit that comment. Easiest and most user friendly method I can think of.

Comment: Sadly, that is not how the design looks like, and I cannot make it custom :/